# Properties file в web проекте

Tags: java, java-ee

Есть код создания соединения с БД для консольного варианта:

```
private static final String PATH_TO_PROPERTIES = "src/main/resources/config.properties";
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream fis = null;            

        try {                
            fis = new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_PROPERTIES);
            prop.load(fis);
            Class.forName(prop.getProperty("driver"));
            String url = prop.getProperty("url_file");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, prop);
        } catch (IOException | SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
```

Все отрабатывает как надо.

При попытке развернуть приложение на локальном Tomcat, файл config.properties попадает в папку WEB-INF, соответственно получаю исключение.
Поиском все советуют использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream foo = loader.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/config.properties");
```

Пробовал, но config.properties никак не виден. Если не использовать свойства и все прописывать явно, то все работает.

Не могу понять, как использовать properties в web-проекте.

Comment: Он вообще-то в папку classes попадает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream foo = loader.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

Сокращенная версия

```
InputStream foo = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

Comment: Да, попадает в classes.  Пробовал "/WEB-INF/classes/config.properties" и "/classes/config.properties" и classes/config.properties" - все равно получаю NullPointerExeption

Comment: Потому что classes это текущая папка для классов. Ты какая папка думал текущая? Предок WEB-INF?

Comment: Ну да. Считал, что WEB-INF - это корень. Так и не понял, что писать в аргумент getResourceAsStream(), ничего не помогает.

Comment: @Tariel может на мой ответ посмотришь под которым пишешь?
Если WEB-INF, корень, то с чего ты WEB-INF в пути писал?

Comment: Так я и справшиваю, как будет правильно, если файл свойств попал в WEB-INF/classes/config.properties?   Просто пробовал по разному, не получается.

Comment: @Tariel я в ответе правильный вариант указал.

Comment: Алекс, спасибо, разобрался, была у меня опечатка, в любом случае помог.   А ешще сбил с толку https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160691/how-to-read-properties-file-in-web-application

Comment: @Tariel какая опечатка?

Comment: @Tariel там все правильно написано. The /WEB-INF folder is not in the root of the classpath. The /WEB-INF/classes folder is. So you need to load the properties files relative to that.

Comment: WEB-INF нужно писать при getServletContext , то есть положить файл в  webapp, тогда его все смогут скачать. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-and-how-to-read-configuration-resource-files-in-servlet-based-app

Comment: Не убрал отладочный код для fis = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(PATH_TO_PROPERTIES);  Значение fis перезаписывалось.